# im running nodejs program and getting symbol lookup error

Tags: node.js, ubuntu

I'm trying to run my program and this error keeps happening. I have man3 and openssl installed.

```
/usr/local/bin/node: symbol lookup error: /root/nomp/node_modules/multi-hashing/build/Release/multihashing.node: undefined symbol: BN_mpi2bn
```

im running node v0.10.29 and npm 1.4.14.

Comment: Is there any package installed on your machine for doing make and build, like ```build-essential``` ?

Comment: yes, i do have build essential

Comment: So see here: https://github.com/zone117x/node-multi-hashing/issues/31#issuecomment-272705726

Comment: will look into it

Comment: i tried doing what somebody suggested in the issue, using npm install and still getting the symbol lookup error when i try to connect